# how do you set your version of dart via pub?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I wasnt sure if i need to update it through their website or something, or if it is possible do call some sort of dart version command which will update DART to be a particular version.

Example:   Dart is either 1.14, or 1.16.  If i want to do it through pub, is there a way to do something like:  `pub set dart 1.15` or something.  I know set isnt a valid command, but i think you get the jist.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your operating system and what system you use to install Dart.

For Debian you can use `apt-get install dart`. `apt-get` allows to pass a specific version number.

For installation options see https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/

In `pubspec.yaml` you can only specify what DART SDK version and dependency versions are supported by a package but it doesn't have and influence which Dart SDK version gets installed.

Comment: Oh, so it is one of those things that pub itself cant handle it, or is outside the scope of permissions for the application?